# LINQ to return distinct value by specific column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `Colour` table like this:

```
Id  Name    VendorId
--------------------
1   Purple  NULL
2   Blue    NULL
3   Black   NULL
4   Purple  1
5   Orange  1
6   Mauve   2
```

And I want to get all colours with `VendorId` as NULL, unless that colour `Name` has an entry with a `VendorId` attached, so e.g. for `VendorId = 1` I'd like

```
Id  Name    VendorId
--------------------
2   Blue    NULL
3   Black   NULL
4   Purple  1
5   Orange  1
```

Noting that the `Purple` row Id `1` with the `NULL VendorId` is not on the list. For `Id = 2` I'd get the rows `1,2,3` and `6`

I thought initially to `.Select .Distinct` on Name but I need the entire object or at least the Id's

```
        var result = _context.Colours
            .Where(x => x.Vendor == null || x.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

but if I use `.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct()` on then I get two instances of `Purple`

How can I achieve this in LINQ?

**Edit:**

I've just tried using

```
        var result = _context.Colours
            .Where(x => x.Vendor == null || x.Vendor.Id == vendorId)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();
```

Trying to get all `null` and `id = 1`, then order by descending Id and trying `.GroupBy` but I got `Client side GroupBy is not supported.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
var vendorId = 1;
var result =
    _context
        .Colours
        .Where(x => x.VendorId == null || x.VendorId == vendorId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.VendorId)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Take(1))
        .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
        .ToList();
```

With this sample data:

```
var colours = new []
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "Purple", VendorId = (int?)null },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Blue", VendorId = (int?)null },
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Black", VendorId = (int?)null },
    new { ID = 4, Name = "Purple", VendorId = (int?)1 },
    new { ID = 5, Name = "Orange", VendorId = (int?)1 },
    new { ID = 6, Name = "Mauve", VendorId = (int?)2 },
};
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: Very interesting exception given for this one: `Processing of the LINQ expression 'xs => xs
    .Take(1)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433` - I think I can add some `ToList()` at points to fix it... maybe...

Comment: Just for anyone else who suffers the same issue, I added `.ToList()` in the chain after the `.OrderByDescending()` otherwise it wouldn't work for me - my client-side couldn't handle the operation.

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me and generating expected results:

```
var idOrNameNotWithId = 
    colours.Where(x => x.VendorId == cid ||
    (!x.VendorId.HasValue && !colours.Where(x => x.VendorId == cid).Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Contains(x.Name)))
    .ToList();
```

The idea behind it: anything with expect cid (colour ID) or anything that's null but only if, when you take anything with ID the name of the colour is not there.

And the full working method. I borrowed the `colour` collection definition from @Enigmativity's answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    var colours = new[]
    {
        new { ID = 1, Name = "Purple", VendorId = (int?)null },
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Blue", VendorId = (int?)null },
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Black", VendorId = (int?)null },
        new { ID = 4, Name = "Purple", VendorId = (int?)1 },
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Orange", VendorId = (int?)1 },
        new { ID = 6, Name = "Mauve", VendorId = (int?)2 },
    };

    var cid = 2;

    var idOrNameNotWithId = 
        colours.Where(x => x.VendorId == cid ||
        (!x.VendorId.HasValue && !colours.Where(x => x.VendorId == cid).Select(x => x.Name).ToList().Contains(x.Name)))
        .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```